# Use decorator in rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

Does anyone know how to use decorator in rabl file?

```
collection @invitations
  child(:user)
   attributes ....
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
collection @invitations
  child(:user => user.decorate)
   attributes ....
```

This is working well

```
object false
child UserDecorator.decorate(current_user)
```

I can't figure out the right syntax for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost have the right answer. I believe you need to switch the order.

```
child(user.decorate => :user)
```

In [rabl's documentation](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#child-nodes), you can add child nodes from an arbitrary data source. Like this:

```
child @posts => :foobar do
  attributes :id, :title
end
```

Another approach would be to decorate the user association when you decorate your invitations. If you're using the [draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper), you could do something like this:

```
class InvitationDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  decorates_association :user
end
```